# In this sentence, does “hubris” parrallel with “démesure”，or does it indicate another future of “Le chrono”?

Tags: sens, expressions

> Le chrono est l’art du juste milieu entre prudence excessive et démesure, ou hubris comme diraient nos amis grecs. >

In this sentence, does “hubris” parrallel with “démesure”，or does it indicate another feature of “Le chrono”？
The sentence is cited from a paragraph of  *SOCRATE À VÉLO*(about some philosophers taking part in Tour de France):

> Vous savez, Thierry, le contre-la-montre est une épreuve où l’on est son propre adversaire. Ce qui importe, c’est donc de bien se connaître soi-même. Il faut être le plus régulier possible et, pour cela, contrôler parfaitement ses limites en ne partant ni trop lentement – car le temps perdu ne se rattrape plus –, ni trop vite – sous peine de s’écrouler. **Le chrono est l’art du juste milieu entre prudence excessive et démesure, ou hubris comme diraient nos amis grecs**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about french language but greek word.

Comment: Cela concerne aussi la façon dont une phrase française s'organise ("In this sentence, does “hubris” parrallel with “démesure" or does it indicate another feature of “Le chrono”？"). C'est plus une question de syntaxe (qui va se résoudre à partir d'indices lexicaux, au moins de façon didactique) que de lexique, français ou grec.

Comment: Thanks a lot! T_T 
It is exactly the structure of the sentence that I can't understand( I know  the meaning of  hubris through the google translation,  but I don't know which it tries to explain: is the word démesure or chrono or art？), and for my poor English I may not put my question in the right way, but thanks for all your answers, now I get it. Thank you！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence "hubris" develops on "démesure". A similar construction:

> Pour mon petit-déjeuner j'ai mangé un pain au chocolat, ou chocolatine comme on dit à Bordeaux.
>
> For my breakfast I had a *pain au chocolat*, also called *chocolatine* in Bordeaux.

The meaning of your sentence is that to be good in "chrono" (time trials), you have to be not too cautious and not too cocky. Then there is a reference to the greek word *hubris* that is used by philosopher to qualify this cockiness they have to avoid to be good at time trials.

Comment: Thank you!  Thanks for your clear explanation，I fully understand.

Comment: @Yanfanyu If I answered your question you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *hubris* (ὕβρις) is the loss of the sense of measure (*phronesis*, or φρόνησις - sometimes translated *caution* or *sagacity*). Le *contre-la-montre* (chrono) is the middle between *hubris* and *phronesis* (a quite aristotelician point of view).

Comment: Thank you so much!